# show that the class is a topology in X

Tags: general-topology

how else can you demonstrate this exercise?

Let $X$ be a nonempty set, $Y$  a topological space with topology $ \Gamma $ and $ f : X \to Y$ a surjective function. Prove that the Class $ \Psi = \{f^{-1} (U) : U \in \Gamma \}$ is a topology in X

That's right? If it is not well demonstrated, thank you for helping me to demonstrate it correctly

Solución:

1. $ \ X \in \Psi$ but for being $ \Gamma $ topology un $ Y, \emptyset, Y \in \Gamma$ And $ f ^{-1}(Y)= X, ~ f ^{-1} ( \emptyset )= \emptyset$
   if  $  \{U_i \}  \subset{} \Psi $ then   $  \displaystyle\bigcup_{i} U_i \in \Psi$
   taking into account that:

$ f^{-1} \ ( \bigcup_{i} U_i ) = \bigcup_i f ^{-1} \ ( U_i) $ .

if $ U, V \in \Psi $ then $ U \cap{} V \in \Psi$

Consequently $ f^{-1} \ ( U \cap{} V ) = f^{-1} \ (U) \cap{} f^{-1} \ (V) $

Comment: Did you mean $f:X\to Y?$ $f:f\to Y$ appears to be nonsense.

Comment: Do you mean $$\Psi=\{f^{-1}(U)\mid U\in \Gamma\}?$$

Comment: To me, too, the surjective function, it seems unnecessary to me, but that is how the exercise was proposed to us, it is to practice. so I ask if there is any better way to show that this class is a topology in X.

Comment: You can’t prove something that is meaningless. If this is exactly how you got the question, ask for clarification from the person who gave you the question. If the errors are on your side, correct your question.

Comment: i just edited the statement please a better way to prove it?

Comment: The formulae you base it on are correct, but you need some more correct wording surrounding it. And $f$ being surjective is not used nor needed.